# split camelCase str regex if characters is upper case?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have this random test random string `"... Jc Yikr Cuduxlor B Az I Ngt FT Jtcmvs Hnrzsv Saegaowyta I..."`  to test regex `"@"(\P{Ll})(\P{Ll}\p{Ll})", "$1 $2" ), @"(\p{Ll})(\P{Ll})", "$1 $2"` " to split camelCase. the problem came FT the regex make "F T" how to make the regex ignore the two string are uppercase?

```
Expected string length 186 but was 185. Strings differ at index 82.
  Expected: "... Jc Yikr Cuduxlor B Az I Ngt F T Jtcmvs Hnrzsv Saegaowyta ..."
  But was:  "... Jc Yikr Cuduxlor B Az I Ngt FT Jtcmvs Hnrzsv Saegaowyta I..."
  --------------------------------------------^

  public static string BreakCamelCase(string str)
  {
   return Regex.Replace( Regex.Replace( str, @"(\P{Ll})(\P{Ll}\p{Ll})", "$1 $2" ), @"(\p{Ll})(\P{Ll})", "$1 $2" );
  }
```

Comment: Don't you need [`Regex.Replace(str, @"(\p{Ll})(\p{Lu})", "$1 $2")`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5cp%7bLl%7d%29%28%5cp%7bLu%7d%29&i=...+Jc+Yikr+Cuduxlor+B+Az+I+Ngt+FT+Jtcmvs+Hnrzsv+Saegaowyta+oI...&r=%241+%242)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a lookahead?

Just to check whether an uppercase character is following it.
But without actually consuming that uppercase character.

And that way the replace string only needs 1 capture group.

**RegEx Pattern**

```
(\p{L})(?=\p{Lu})
```

**C#**

```cs
public static string BreakCamelCase(string str)
{
   return Regex.Replace(str, @"(\p{L})(?=\p{Lu})", "$1 ");
}
```

**Explaining the pattern**

> (\p{L})    : 1st Capturing Group ($1) matching any kind of letter from
>   any language
>
> (?=\p{Lu}) : Positive Lookahead to check for an uppercase letter that
>   has a lowercase variant